# Cannot set focus on Text Box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus

I have a form with 4 textboxes. This form is viewed inside a split container panel.
 I can enter the values inside the text box but after the value, I click on the text I entered to modify a value but it is not letting me click, there is no cursor coming on the text box, the only thing I can do is backspace or select all and delete.
I cant click anywhere on the middle of the text entered. 
If I check the focus I see it is false.
Can someone tell me what could be the problem and how to set the focus to the text box?

To show the form on the panel this is what I am doing

```
splitContainerControl1.PanelVisibility = DevExpress.XtraEditors.SplitPanelVisibility.Both;
splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
myform.TopLevel = false;
myform.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Add(myform);
myform.Show();
```

I have tried the below, but not working, I see focus still false.

```
myform.Focus();
myform.textbox_latitude.Select();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please show us how `myform` is declared and instantiated. [mcve]

Comment: It is declared and instantiated in the main forms declaration and initialization.

MyPointsForm myform = null;
myform = new MyPointsForm();

Then it is displayed on a panel on the main form, by a button click from the main form

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.ActiveControl`:

```
this.ActiveControl = textbox_latitude;
```

Or if you want to focus it on the child form:

```
myform.ActiveControl = textbox_latitude;
```